# How to encrypt(?) a document to prove it was made at a certain time?

Tags: python, validation, authentication, encryption, jupyter-notebook

So, a bit of a strange question, but let's say that I have a document (jupyter notebook) and I want to be able to prove to someone that it was made before a certain date, or that it was created on a certain date - does anyone have any ideas as to how I'd achieve that?

It would need to be a solution that couldn't be technically re-engineered after the fact (faking the creation date).

Keen to hear your thoughts :) !

Comment: email it to yourself or a trusted party

Comment: If you have to "back date" it and this isn't a future problem for docs you are going to make, say tomorrow, then you are kind of out of luck.

Comment: Digital signatures usually include a timestamp. But the authenticity of that timestamp can only be proven by a trusted third party.

Answer (score 0):

email it to yourself or a trusted party – dandavis yesterday

Good solution.
Thanks!

Comment: How would this prove anything?